# Flutter local notifications : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I'm attempting to create local notifications for my Flutter app, but I have an issue when compiling.

My code :

```dart
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationService {
  static final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future detailsNotification() async {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channel id', 'channel name',
            channelDescription: 'channel description',
            importance: Importance.max),
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails());
  }

  static Future init({bool initScheduled = false}) async {
    final android = AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
    final ios = IOSInitializationSettings();
    final settings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: ios);
    await notifications.initialize(settings,
        onSelectNotification: (payload) async {});
  }

  static Future envoyerNotification(
          {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payload}) async =>
      notifications.show(id, title, body, await detailsNotification(),
          payload: payload);
}
```

The error I get :

```
E/flutter (28521): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
E/flutter (28521):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setSmallIcon(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:304)
E/flutter (28521):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:215)
E/flutter (28521):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1009)
E/flutter (28521):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1347)
E/flutter (28521):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1226)
E/flutter (28521):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
```

I've seen a similar topic on StackOverflow, but the only answer was to use Firebase, and I don't want to use it.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

you need to add the icon parameter in the constructor for the android details

icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).